# Processing and visualizing data to show Doppler shift

Tags: signal-processing

I want to write a program which can read a .wav file and manipulate the data so I can observe the Doppler effect in a plot. My problem is I can't figure out a way to isolate the frequency x time.

This is my program so far.

```
data = Import[lamaior, "Data"];

ListLinePlot[data[[1, 1 ;; 300]], 
  AxesLabel -> {"tempo(ms)", "amplitude"}]
ListLinePlot[data, 
  AxesLabel -> {"tempo(ms)", "amplitude"}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: are you aware of [that](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-sound-and-signal-processing/measuring-car-velocity-via-acoustic-doppler-effect.html). So far I remember, it's a extract from a WTC conference gigen by Marcus Van Almsick.

Comment: I don't remember wich WTC Conference it was, and there are many. If you are not aware and if you are interested, I can try to look for it.

Comment: How about Spectrogram... presumably the Doppler shift will appear as a change in the instantaneous frequency of the signal.

Comment: @andre please! I would like to take a look.

Comment: [Link to Marcus Van Alsick's conference](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?sx=almsick&v=1387) about Doppler effect measurments (among other things). Look at time =12.6seconds